# Using c# library on IOS device using monotouch

Tags: xamarin.ios

We have an existing c# library that we would like to re-use in an IOS application. It looks like this is easily done using monotouch IF we are willing to use monotouch for the entire application. However, we would like to use xcode as the primary tool (and thereby obj-c) since we feel that it for our purposes is more 'clean'.

Looking at stackoverflow and xamarin.com, it looks like it was possible in 2009 using 'monotouch --xcode'. Later posts by Miguel indicates that this is no longer supported even though it is still available in monotouch.

I have tried to make a very simple c# assembly and run 'monotouch --xcode=/projectpath myassembly.dll. I can open the project in xcode 4.2, but any attempts to build it fails with 200+ errors "Apple LLVM compiler 3., Invalid instruction mnemonic 'bl'"

Has anyone made this work recently using xcode 4.* and monotouch 5.*?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Use MonoTouch Library in Xcode Project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755443/how-to-use-monotouch-library-in-xcode-project)